# Linked in url returning the response code 999

Tags: java

I need to implement the crawl code in LinkedIn.

I have tried `httpUrlConnection.Open` connection and 
my LinkedIn url opens in browser perfectly, but while I am using the java code I am getting a response code 999.

Please suggest the correct thing that I have to do.

Comment: Please post your code, the console error, the object being passed, anything relevant to this, otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [999 Error Code on HEAD request to LinkedIn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231113/999-error-code-on-head-request-to-linkedin)