# 999 Unknown Error for LinkedIn link work on localhost but not o production server

Tags: java, http

My Code below:

```
    System.out.println("Linkedin URL="+"https://"+linkedinUrl);
    Document aResponseDocument= null;               
    //Connection.Response aResponse = Jsoup.connect("https://www.linkedin.com/in/noah-bennett-453a4833").cookies(response.cookies()).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
    Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("https://"+linkedinUrl)
    //.referrer("http://localhost:8080")
    //.headers(headerMap)                       
    .cookies(response.cookies())
    .method(Connection.Method.GET);
```

this work using localhost but when run on production server it returned `HTTP response code: 999` for URL.

Comment: Please use the Code Block markup tool to format your code appropriately so we can read it.

Comment: Maybe its about the header. Check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231113/999-error-code-on-head-request-to-linkedin